# How do you implement a login warning banner in Gnome 3?

Tags: linux, gnome, warning

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/79522/how-do-you-implement-a-warning-banner-in-fedora) documents how we used to inflict the mandatory login banners required on our Linux machines at work.  Unfortunately, this procedure is no longer effective with Gnome 3 in Fedora 15 & 16.  Gnome 3 seems to ignore the banner_message fields in gconf-editor.

Does Gnome 3 provide an equivalent procedure that allows us to present a warning message to users prior to login?

NOTE: Moving this line of inquiry to here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38420/how-do-you-implement-a-login-warning-banner-in-gnome-3